How do differentials work as tensors
So I'm trying to understand how tensors work on a basic level because they were mentioned in my geometry course as those object that represent multilinear forms and in my analysis course as the object that could be used to more generally represent differentials while talking about the taylor expansion of a function between vector spaces. So far I know that tensors can be thought of as multidimensional arrays, and I know how for a multilinear form you can say that applying a tensor looks like this, for example a degree 3 tensor applied to three vectors: $$T(x,y,z)=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^{n} T_{ijk}x_iy_jz_k$$
But when talking about differentials, those are not multilinear forms, they are just multilinear maps, but for example the second differential takes two vectors as inputs but in my head it should be a tensor of degree 3, not 2, since it should be a vector of hessian matrices, one per dimension of the codomain of the function. But then how can the application of a differential to the increments be explicitely expressed using tensors like the formula I typed before? Does it even make sense to do this?

You should read up on tensor products first. For any three vector spaces $U, V, W$ we have that the linear maps
$$
  U\otimes V \to W\quad\text{and}\quad U\to V^*\otimes W
$$
are the "same thing".
In other words we have a canonical isomorphism
$$
  \mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V, W) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(U, V^*\otimes W).
$$
Note also the double dual isomorphism $(V^*)^* \cong V$ and the canonical associativity
$$
  U\otimes (V\otimes W) \cong (U\otimes V)\otimes W.
$$

A differential is a linear map $V \to W$, but this is the same thing as a map $V\otimes W^* \to \mathbb R$ which is the same thing as $V\otimes W^*\to\mathbb R$, which is the same thing as a bilinear form $V\times W^* \to \mathbb R$. If it happens that $V, W$ are tensor products, say $V = U^{\otimes k}$ and $W = U^{\otimes l}$, then $V\otimes W^* \to \mathbb R$ is the same as $U^{\otimes k}\otimes (U^*)^{\otimes l} \to \mathbb R$, which is a type $(k,l)$ multilinear form.

but how do differentials work within the tensor product? I get that for example the first order differential is a linear map U->V which is "the same" as U(x)V*->R, which is a tensor of degree 2, so one higher than the order of the differential, but i still don't get how the differential can be represented by that map... how is U(x)V*->R made? How is it applied to an increment to get the increment in the codomain of the function? How does the tensor work if it's still the jacobian (which needs to be applied to a vector, not to an element of U(x)V*)

@dumb_ptr If $f : U \to V$ then we get $f' : U\otimes V^* \to \mathbb R$ by $$f'(u\otimes\omega) = \omega(f(u)),$$ and in the opposite direction you need a tensor contraction over $V$ (which I notate $\mathrm{Tr}$ with $\eta\in V^$ and $w\in V$ dummy variables) $$f(u) = \mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}_{\eta(w)}f'(u\otimes\eta)w = \sum_if'(u\otimes e^i)e_i.$$ The last equality is the representation of the contraction over a basis $e_i\in V$ with dual basis $e^i\in V^$.
